using express-session middleware getting error cannot access session data in other endpoints
started learning backend and chatgpt couldnt help
INDEX.js (my server sending request to api)

import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";
import session from "express-session";


const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'kartikrao2004!',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "http://localhost:4000";

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Add JSON parsing middleware

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs");
});

//to open signup page
app.get("/signup",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("signup.ejs");
});

//home in nav bar
app.get("/start",async(req,res)=>{
    try{
    const response= await axios.get(`${API_URL}/start`);
    console.log(response.data.fname);
    res.render("starting.ejs",{name:response.data.fname,});
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
});
//login form submit
app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/login`, req.body);
        console.log(response.data);
        res.render("starting.ejs",{name:response.data.fname,});

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});
//for logout
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('sessionId'); // Clear session ID cookie
    res.redirect('/'); // Redirect to login page after logout
});

app.post("/signup",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const response=await axios.post(`${API_URL}/signup`,req.body);
            res.redirect("/");
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error("Error:",error);
        res.render("signup.ejs",{message:"Email or username already exists"});
    }
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

My api.js file
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from "pg";
import session from "express-session";

const app = express();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'kartikrao2004!',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
const port = 4000;

const db = new pg.Client({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "blog",
    password: "kart2004!",
    port: 5432,
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Add JSON parsing middleware

db.connect()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    });


//login checker
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
       
        const result = await db.query("select id,fname,lname from customer where username=($1) and password=($2)", [req.body.username, req.body.password]);
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(result.rows);

        if (result.rows.length !== 0) {
            const data = result.rows[0]; 
            req.session.userId = data.id;
            req.session.fname = data.fname; // Assign fname to session
            console.log("User logged in. First name:", req.session.fname);
            res.json(data);
        } else {
            res.status(404).send("User not found");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    } 
});

//home tag 
app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Session data:", req.session); // Debug log
    console.log("First name:", req.session.fname); // Debug log

    if (req.session.fname) {
        console.log("User's first name:", req.session.fname); // Debug log
        res.status(200).json({ fname: req.session.fname });
    } else {
        res.status(404).send("First name not found in session");
    }
});


// for signup
app.post("/signup",async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.body);
         await db.query("insert into customer (fname,lname,email,username,password) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)",[req.body.fname,req.body.lname,req.body.email,req.body.username,req.body.password]);
         res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully signed up" });
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
process.on('exit', () => {
    db.end();
    console.log('Database connection closed');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

In index.js file whenever i want to change something or validate i send request to my api to access the database and do the changes
here in api.js when /login is called req.session.fname and userid both show data that it is getting created
but when it goes to /start (when home link is pressed get request goes to api.js through index.js)  req.session.fname is becoming undefined i cannot understand why tried all combinations but cant find solution
Basically what the code for now is about is after login my id,fname from the database, i am storing that in session so that in future multiple user can use website at same time.
when logging in it successfully does its operation and api creates sessioon.fname and id but when i press the home key it should reoute me to the starting file which i want to do but it shows error
that in /start in api.js the session.fname is undefined, because of which i cant send my data to index.js
What can i possibly do?
